# Calculate difference week to week in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

What I am wanting to do is show in one cell the difference in values from week to week. What I am doing is tracking weight loss totals and we are wanting to enter the current weight for the week and calculate the difference to the previous week; this is over 10 week period.

Example: Week 1 = B, Week 2 = C, Week 3 = D, Week 4 = E
This goes on for 10 total weeks.

When B is entered, nothing should happen; when C is entered it should calculate the difference from B; when D is entered it would calculate the difference from C. The thing is, I would want this to change only for the one cell that has the calculation.

These values are in a row. Week 1 is column B, week 2 is column C and so on. The calculation would be in column O.

Thanks for the help!!!
Regards,
J

Comment: First of all ... best wishes for your weight loss program. Now to the issue, this seems to be an easy Excel function solution. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I think my biggest issue is using the right terminology when searching for a solution. It seems like a i could use Lookup in some way, but I am not sure what it is I am looking for. Would this be considered running values, or maybe cumulative? Quite honestly, if I knew that I could probably find it. And it certainly seems to be an easy function but ignorance is slowing me down :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will need to nest a series of if statements like so:

```
=IF(K4,K4-J4,IF(J4,J4-I4,IF(I4,I4-H4,IF(H4,H4-G4,IF(G4,G4-F4,IF(F4,F4-E4,IF(E4,E4-D4,IF(D4,D4-C4,IF(C4,C4-B4,"")))))))))
```

Then it should assess your cells in reverse order applying your desired calculation only when a cell is populated.

Comment: This worked perfectly; i was able to take what you taught me here and use it to calculate the Week to Week percent change:
=IF(L2>0,O2/L2,(IF(K2>0,O2/K2,(IF(J2>0,O2/J2,(IF(I2>0,O2/I2,(IF(H2>0,O2/H2,(IF(G2>0,O2/G2,(IF(F2>0,O2/F2,(IF(E2>0,O2/E2,(IF(D2>0,O2/D2,(IF(C2>0,O2/C2,"")))))))))))))))))))

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok ... so this might have been solved by using helper cells ... but then I guess you were looking for a single formula. So i tried this using `ArrayFormula`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C2:K2,MATCH(2,1/(C2:K2<>"")))-OFFSET(INDEX(C2:K2,MATCH(2,1/(C2:K2<>""))),0,-1),"")
```

You would need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: @pnuts - Updated both your review comments :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C2:K2,,MATCH(1E+100,C2:K2))-INDEX(B2:K2,,MATCH(1E+100,B2:K2)-1),"")
```

[image: SO21733418 example]